# How to apply "One Assertion Per Test" for OR relation condition

Tags: unit-testing, assert

It's recognized that "One Assertion Per Test" in assertion. It is not good to write assertion like below：

```
  Assert((foo != null) && (bar != null));
```

The better chocie is:

```
  Assert(foo != null);
  Assert(bar != null);
```

The question is what if the assertion is:

```
  Assert((foo == null) || (foo.length == 0));
```

The relationship is OR instead of AND.

Is there any way to make "One Assertion per test" while keep the logic?

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind the guideline is that you only test one logical thing (which may boil down to a **few** asserts in some cases) in one test. Therefore if a test fails, you know the exact reason why it failed and can zone in into the specific block of code in a snap. To borrow an example from [this page](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=35578), if the following test fails, I know something is wrong with how country is extracted/determined in the Address type.

```
public void testCountry() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("COUNTRY",  anAddress.getCountry());
    }
```

Compare this with the version of the test with multiple asserts, it could fail for multiple reasons (and unless you use helpful assert messages) you'd need to **debug the test** (yuck!).

I'd need to see your complete test. From what it see, it seems to be that you're checking a collection for a something-not-found scenario. In which case, the recommendation is to return an empty collection so that the clients don't have to check for null. Since your test is also a client, it's life is also made simpler : `Assert.AreEqual (0, foo.length)`

Comment: Good answer! Unit test means testing **one** unit in **one** situation.

Answer (score 4):

The problem could not in the assertion, but in the [Arrange or Act](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert) part of the testcase: when you unit-test, you invoke a [small] piece of code in a **controlled environment**. That is to say that you should know how the software under test will behave, and thus, know whether it will return a null pointer, or an empty string. **Every test shall have one expected result**.

... Unless you're using your test against several functions/methods that behave differently, or some third-party code that appears to behave differently in different situations.
If this is the case, the "One assertion per rule" is just a guideline, and you can use the assertion as shown is the question. If this test fails, it will mean that the returned foo is a non-empty string.

Or, you could create a function to test for empty strings that will also test if the string pointer is not null:

```
Assert(is_empty_string(foo));
```

Your language string class may provide this method.

Answer (score 1):

Sure: one test ensures a null foo asserts, one ensures a non-null foo with 0 length also fails (and others check the cases[s] where foo is not null *and* has length != 0).  How is it any hander than checking an AND?

Edit: pseudocode as requested...:

```
  should_assert(themethod(foo=null))
  fakefoo = fakewhatever(length=0)
  should_assert(themethod(foo=fakefoo))
  ...rest of tests w/foo not null, w/length != 0
```

e.g., in a Python unittest w/a still-pseudocode `mock`, this might be:

```
  self.assertRaises(AssertionError, theobj.themethod, null)
  fakefoo = mock.makeObj(length=0)
  self.assertRaises(AssertionError, theobj.themethod, fakefoo))
  ...rest of tests w/foo not null, w/length != 0
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with python. But, I'm still confused.
Can I translate it to below?
  Assert(foo == null);
  Assert(foo.length == 0);
This doesn't look right.

Comment: Uh? If you assert both that's an AND, so of course it doesn't look right... asserting an OR means, e.g., assert(A or B) -> if not A then assert B -- in Python or anywhere else!-)

Comment: or rather: if A then assert(False) else assert(B);-)

Comment: Got it.
I'm using C# which might not be powerful as python. the signature of Assert is like below:
  "Assert(bool condition, string msg);"

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: C#'s power and Python's are roughly comparable -- Assert(foo==null || foo.length==0, "invalid foo: non-null & non-empty") [[I imagine the msg is emitted if the assert fails, and De Morgan's law says that (not(a or b)) == (not a and not b)]].